# Is Eclipse IDE has in-built Internal JDK?

Tags: java

My system doesn't have JDK installed, but I can see my Java programs are running in Eclipse and getting perfect output. How is it possible?

Comment: Almost all IDEs can download and use a JDK on the fly if there can't be a installed one found.
Since Eclipse itself is written in Java it brings Java with it embedded. At least a JRE which can run simple Java SE things as well - but for complex applications you need a JDK

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse comes with a JRE packaged as plugin. Checkout the plugins folder.

Comment: So without installing java software we can do any java work right?

Comment: Yes. That's also the same with NetBeans or IntelliJ. The reason is: All these tools are also written in Java and need the Java runtime

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse comes with built in JRE & it depends on which eclipse version you have downloaded.

How to confirm, go to eclipse & :

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java ->Compiler-> Compiler Complience leve.
```

Here, you can see different versions of java compiler. Select one version or by default, one of higher version is automatically selected for you.

After that,

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java->Installed JRE's-> here you will see path of JRE that shipped with eclipse
```

And this is reason why your code in eclipse runs well as built in JRE is automatically used if no external jre is used.